# Too Many Levels of Symbolic Links for KeyTool

Tags: linux, centos, keytool

Running the following path in order to short link keytool, which is used for secure key / certificate generation

```
ln -sf $(dirname 'readlink -f $(which java)')/keytool /usr/bin/keytool
```

Getting the following error when I run it

```
ln: failed to access '/usr/bin/keytool': Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Can only access machine via SSH, could use some advice on how to resolve this

Comment: What is the effect of **single-quoting** in the shell?? Specifically, what do you think `dirname 'readlink -f $(which java)'` returns? (hint: it's not what you think it is, and is most likely a reference to the current directory `'.'`) which if you attempt to create a symlink for `/usr/bin/keytool` pointing to `./keytool` may cause problems you are not expecting)

Comment: What would you suggest the revised statement look like?

Comment: If you can guarantee `java` exists (usually as a link in `/usr/bin` also), then `ln -sf "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$(which java)")")"/keytool /usr/bin/keytool` should work. You need to protect against a `space` in the path at each level of *command-substitution* (thus the multiple levels of double-quotes). Give it a go and let me know.

Comment: For example, on my system `dirname "$(readlink -f "$(type -p java)")"` returns `/usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0/jre/bin`. (you can use `type -p` in place of `which` and prevent an additional subshell)